# how to get rid of VS-Code errors on when writing WooCoomerce functions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I keep having red highlights errors in VS-CODE when i write woocommerce functions and it's annoying how to get rid of those errors

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error highlights are there for a reason. Either fix them (hover them and they will reveal what's wrong/or go to the "Problems" panel) or disable/deinstall whatever plugin is so kind to check your code for mistakes you made.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do following task.

1. Install latest version of Visual Studio Code
2. Install "Wordpress Snippet" Plugin
3. Install woocommerce plugin.
4. Restart your pc and run VS Code again

Comment: Does woocommerce plugin comes with some kind of error detection? If that's the case, installing is just does what the question asks to get rid of.

Comment: yes woocommerce functions are considered as not defined in vs-code